# CSS @font-face not working in IE8

Tags: css, font-face

I have tried reading multiple articles on how to deal with custom fonts in IE, but they never seemed to work for me. I tried converting the fonts to `EOT`, but that didn't seem to work either. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, so I will post my code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Klavika Regular";
    src: url('../fonts/klavika.eot');
    src: local('â˜º'), url('../fonts/klavika.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/klavika.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/klavika.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

this works in ie8/9

http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/serif/alegreya/demo.html

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AftaserifRegular';
    src: url('AftaSerifThin-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('AftaSerifThin-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('AftaSerifThin-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('AftaSerifThin-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('AftaSerifThin-Regular-webfont.svg#AftaserifRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Why was local('â˜º') removed? What is it for?

Comment: its another trick to get font-face to play nicely with ie. you can read about the different font-face solutions on paul irish's blog.

Answer (score 0):

if IE8 *thinks* it supports any other format other than `eot` of the ones listed below, then it will probably try to use that one. Maybe you could use a IE8 hack, like

```
src: local('â˜º'), url('../fonts/klavika.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/klavika.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/klavika.svg') format('svg');
src /*\**/: url('../fonts/klavika.eot')\9
```

so only IE8 will read the last `src` line and thus load the .eot.

Comment: Didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try three kinds of CSS Formats for @font-face on [FontSquirrel Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) (in "EXPERT..." mode > in section "CSS Formats:" > "more information")

Comment: Well, site looks awesome and all but the "Download your kit" button doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try to reload page and reload your font by http://d.pr/U1yY I advise you to read posts on the links "more information"( http://d.pr/r0Fn )

Comment: Yea, got it. But it includes only HTML and stylesheet, no fonts tho'

Comment: What font file (extension) you use (that  FontSquirrel Generator can't work with)? And if you open HTML that you'v got, is there any information using your font?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking to see if your .htaccess file allows the file type.