# commercial fonts can not be seen in webpage

Tags: css, fonts

I am using two commercial fonts  *FrenchScriptStd* and *FuturaStd-Light*  (I have bought them separately and then using them to create a webpage)

This is my first page using this kind of fonts which are commercial (I have tried googlefonts but they do not have these fonts)...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FrenchScriptStd';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('FrenchScriptStd'), url('css/FrenchScriptStd.ttf') format('ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FuturaStd-Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('FuturaStd-Light'), url('css/FuturaStd-Light.ttf') format('ttf');
}

#fontface1{font-family : Font1; }
h1{font-family : Font1; }
#fontface2{font-family : Font2; }
#nav a {font-family : Font2;}
```

so the french font i want to be displayed when using *h1* and futura font when using *#nav a*

```
/*  Typography
=============================================================== */
h1 { color:#cc6602; font-size:36px; font-family:FrenchScriptStd, arial, serif; font-weight:normal; padding-bottom:14px; }

#nav a {font-family:FuturaStd-Light, arial, serif; text-decoration:none; color:#a8241b; font-size:20px; text-shadow:0 1px #fff; display: block; }
```

In my pc it seems to work, but in some computers it is not displaying correctly, 
Is there a way to correct this, maybe i am messing something up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would look into [Paul Irish's bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley) as the reason why you cannot see the font on 'some computers' is the fact that these computers may have different browsers installed than the browser you were originally testing on that need different font files, other than TrueType.

A syntax that I use and have a lot of success with is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FrenchScriptStd';
    src: url('css/FrenchScriptStd.eot');
    src: url('css/FrenchScriptStd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/FrenchScriptStd.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/FrenchScriptStd.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('css/FrenchScriptStd.svg#FrenchScriptStd') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I believe that this is the @font-face style FontSquirrel uses.

Note that in your example you have not converted the font to various web formats. Here are some services that you can use online to get all of the files converted:

- [FontSquirell](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
- [Free Font Converter](http://www.freefontconverter.com/)
- [OTF to WOFF](http://orionevent.comxa.com/otf2woff.html)
- [Font Kit Generator](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/)

You should then host these font files locally as you may run into issues with MIME types and headers and the FireFox browser not downloading the font files if the files are hosted externally and not on the same domain for which they are being used.

Also, [your milage will vary](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face) in mobile browsers and older versions of IE. :)

Comment: I should note, I have no idea what your font's licence said in regards to usage of these fonts online when you bought them. While I encourage you to use the conversion tools above, I make no comment on whether or not your usage licence allows you to make such conversions. The conversion sites listed have better worded Terms of Use :) that you may want to read..

Comment: Alright I was reading them, also the last site "Font Kit generator is good", I am testing the solution

Comment: How would you add the h1 functionality, I was doing this but had no luck #fontface1{font-family : FrenchScriptStd; }  and #fontface1{font-family : Font1; }  how is it supposed to be added I am a little confused

Comment: If you declare a font-family (or any other CSS property) twice for the same ID in your CSS, the second one wins. So, in this case (your comment above) as #fontface1 is the same ID the font-family will be the font called 'Font1', not 'FrenchScriptStd'. For ease of an example, I made this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jy4cD/1/ using the font in question, that I managed to find online for free, convert to correct formats and host on my Dropbox account. Note that this example will not work in FireFox as the fonts are externally hosted. I hope this helps.

Comment: in firefox I added src: local(font name), url("font_name.ttf"); and seems to work, do not know why is not working on IE...

Comment: Hmm... You're right, my jsFiddle link wasn't working in IE. I don't have a lot of experience with IE 9 but have managed to get it working by just hosting the fonts locally: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7573777/zzz_test/frenchscriptstd1348417236/frenchscriptstd.html Download this font kit here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7573777/zzz_test/frenchscriptstd1348417236/frenchscriptstd1348417236.zip I made it with fontface.codeandmore.com. The fonts here are just hosted locally and work in all the big browsers, but not IE 8. I think that fontface.codeandmore.com may just be converting the files incorrectly.

Comment: PS these folks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8 seem to be having the same issue. The answer with the highest votes suggests the syntax I suggested using. Give it one more shot in IE8, but don't loose sleep over it. I have found it buggy and difficult to support @font-face in older versions of IE.

Comment: Ok, I think IE9 is good enough, I have found always IE to be a headache}

Comment: I agree very much! :) Thanks for the upvote! :) Good luck with it all.

Comment: Thanks go for you @jonny.milano  :P

Answer (score -3):

The fonts have to be installed on every computers on which your web page shall be displayed.

Comment: So, I have to develop some kind of aplication to download the fonts  for users?, or maybe use a flash solution...

Comment: Yes, one or the other. You should verify the license agreement that comes along with the fonts you've bought, because you may not have the right to reditribute them freely. In which case the download solution is not possible. And, even if it is possible, it is very unlikely that the user does so. That's why no website does that.

Comment: oh, thats a shame, so the best solution would be to use flash and images of each letter right?

Comment: If you just wand to display text with your special fonts, Flash is overkill. The solution is usually to render the text into an image, and display that image in the webpage.

Comment: I shall also highlight that it is recommanded to stick to usual fonts for a website, for clarity and simplicity. Special fonts shall be used only for a few carefully selected cases: title, logo, menu items. The body of the page is best left alone with the standard sans-serif font, which renders almost identically on every computer and web browser.

Comment: this is a very old answer alexandre!