# IE8 not picking up my @font-face

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I've almost finished my website, but there is one tiny issue with IE8...
I'm using a @font-face of the FutureStd Medium font, and every browser but IE8 managed to pick this up.

I tried already all the given tips & tricks available on the internet, but no luck.

- replace the `'` with `"`
- place the including of the stylesheets in the `<body>` rather then the `<head>`
- let different generators generate the .eot file

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "CustomFutura";
  src: url("fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
       url("fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.ttf")  format("truetype"),
       url("fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And if it might help, [this is the link to the site](http://032.www.be.eurorscg.net/)...

What else can I do to get this thing working in IE8?

Comment: please see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'CustomFutura';
    src: url('fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.eot');
    src: url('fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.eot?iefix') format('eot'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck... The only thing changed is the `#` being left out and the `"embedded-opentype"` changed to `'eot'`, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, I just copied a working font-face and used your file names and locations...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it did.