# custom font not working in IE 8

Tags: css

The font code is not working in IE8.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_DBModern';
    src: url('fonts/DBModern.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DBModern.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/DBModern.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/DBModern.svg#Conv_DBModern') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
}

.header_everywhere_text {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Conv_DBModern';
    font-size: 5.44em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 150px;
    width: 1030px; 
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS @font-face not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: Thanks but still not working.I have a .otf file and I converted it to webfont using font2web.com  to get all the necessary files.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.There was another font family working.Many thanks.