# Font-face not working on IE8 Down

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I've looked this online and can't see anything wrong with my font-face css, but however it isn't working on IE 8 and lower, so would love to see if anyone knows how fix this issue or if there is anything they see I'm doing wrong.

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Univers-CondensedBold';
src: url('univers-condensedbold.eot');
src: url('univers-condensedbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('univers-condensedbold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('univers-condensedbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('univers-condensedbold.svg#univers-condensedbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-smooth: always;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Univers-Light';
src: url('univers-light.eot');
src: url('univers-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('univers-light.woff') format('woff'),
     url('univers-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('univers-light.svg#univers-light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-smooth: always;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: **[CSS @font-face not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8)**

Comment: What "isn't working" means exactly? Text is displayed in a fallback font? Add the CSS rule, where the `font-family` property is declared. Also make sure that the rule isn't overwritten.