# font face not working on IE7 & IE8 and working on IE9,10, Firefox, and all other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

This is my css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'droidnaskhbold';
    src: url('../../fonts_new/droidnaskh.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts_new/droidnaskh.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts_new/droidnaskh.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts_new/droidnaskh.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts_new/droidnaskh.svg#droidnaskhbold') format('svg');
}
```

I can't get it work on IE7 & IE8
any help please

Comment: You answered your own question. font-face does not work in IE7/IE8. It works in IE9 and up.see note here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: Then How can I get it work in IE7,8. I have seen too many websites have this technique, Thanks

Comment: Repeat of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: Font-face did not exist in 2008- therefor those browsers cannot support it. And I really cant think of a viable way to use a polyfil. Sometimes you just have to accept if the user wants to live in 2008 then they get a 2008 version of the web...

Comment: Good point, Some people really wanna still live in 2008. Their problem not mine

Comment: @Daniel and Chris: That is simply incorrect. IE has supported font-face since IE4 in 1997. For once, IE was first at something. This is probably related to relative/absolute path, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font-face has been supported [by IE5.5 and up](http://caniuse.com/fontface), and EOT fonts [since IE6](http://caniuse.com/eot) so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Without some more code, it's hard to tell what's wrong here. Lack of `:before` support, wrong path to fonts, downloading of fonts disabled in IE's security settings?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to StackOverflow. Actually, `font-face` with TTF was supported already in IE4 (1997). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_4

Comment: That table refers to IE4 being able to use system TTF fonts, not custom ones with `font-face`. TTF fonts through `font-face` weren't supported untill IE9 — with the caveat that the font's embedding permissions are set to "installable."