# @font-face not working in IE8 but works in chrome, firefox?

Tags: css, font-face

css code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sky2-webfont';
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.ttf');
}
```

it works fine in chrome and firefox. but not in IE8.

when i add .eot font for IE in css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sky2-webfont';
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.ttf');
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.eot');
}
```

its works in IE8 but not in chrome and firefox.

how to make it work in all browsers???

**EDIT**

tried Font Squirrel . that too didn't work.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sky2-webfont';
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.ttf');
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.eot'),
  url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
     url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2-webfont.svg#leb-webfont') format('svg');
}
```

**This one worked.**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sky2-webfont';
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.eot');
src: url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
     url('http://swaidanews.com/CMS/fonts-sky/sky2.svg#sky2-webfont') format('svg');
}
```

but still i don't understand, the fonts are in the 'fonts-sky' folder

```
sky2-webfont.woff
sky2-webfont.ttf
sky2-webfont.eot
sky2-webfont.svg
```

but in css @font-face we are using simply

```
sky2.woff
sky2.eot
sky2.svg
sky2.ttf
```

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS @font-face not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: Every browser has its own preferred font type. Have a look at [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create the perfect @font-face rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 has only partial support has you can see here: http://caniuse.com/fontface

This is what I'd use:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sky2-webfont';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: local('☺'), 
         url('font.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('font.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('font.svg#webfontzVgQprWy') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the font in **.eot**, **.woff**, **.ttf** and **.svg** formats. This way your layout will display correctly through all major web browsers.

Your CSS would be like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
    src: url('droid-sans/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('droid-sans/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('droid-sans/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('droid-sans/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('droid-sans/DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

As an example, Google Fonts develops its webfont kits using **.woff** formats, as can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3a).

Comment: I tried this. converted the font using Font Squirrel and tried the same layout. not worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sky2';
    src: url('sky2.eot');
    src: url('sky2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sky2.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sky2.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('sky2.svg#sky2') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```