# Custom icon font not working correctly on IE8

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8

We're using an icon font-face to show social media icons on our website, but they are not displaying correctly in IE8.

Oddly though, they show up fine on our test server, just not when the site is live, as can be seen here -

**Test Server**
[image: Icons on our test server]
**Live Server**
[image: Icons on the live server]

I'm guessing that the server config could be the culprit here, but I don't really know what to look for. Does anybody know what could be causing this? Thanks.

Here is the CSS I use, generated by [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/#/select) -

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'DD_Icons';
    src: url('fonts/DD_Icons.eot');
}
@font-face{
    font-family: 'DD_Icons';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('truetype'),
         url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon-facebook:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-twitter:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-google-plus:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e603";
}
.icon-feed:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-linkedin:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e605";
}
.icon-DD-Options:before{
    font-family: "DD_Icons" !important;
    content: "\e600";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Apparently IE8 has trouble rendering the icon fonts because it doesn't support using both `@font-face` and the `:before` pseudo-element together. You can read more about this issue here, with a possible solution in the comment by Adam:

http://andymcfee.com/2012/04/04/icon-fonts-pseudo-elements-and-ie8/

Answer (score 1):

Either the network is blocking this external file from being brought in (by file type, possibly) or Network Policy is blocking this as an IE configuration.

This happened to me for a site we were building for a large client of ours.  Their IE9 was quite locked down.

But, for the record, you CAN use icon fonts in IE8.  We do it all the time.  View this page in IE8 to see:  http://fontawesome.io/whats-new/

I believe the reason the linked article says pseudo elements and icon fonts don't work together is because he's trying to implement an icon font for actual letters- i.e. content:"A".

However, look behind the scenes at the way FontAwesome implements them:

```
<span class="icon-home"></span>
```

becomes:

```
.icon-home:before {
    content: "\e900";
}
```

That \e900 is part of the [private use area of Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)  This means that if the .woff or .eot file is blocked, you see , instead of a symbol.

You could, however, use a tool like http://icomoon.io to select icon you want to use and customize it to use, instead, a different unicode value that looks similar to the target icon.

This page (http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/all/) proved very valuable for that endeavor.

```
.icon-home:before {
    content: "\2602";
}
```

becomes ☂ if the font-file is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the .eot file for the fallback when SVG's aren't supported. See this thread for the formats you need [CSS @font-face not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8)