# Google fonts not loading in Windows browsers, but do load on Mac browsers

Tags: css, windows, macos, google-api

Stackers.

I'm working as the Front End guy on [www.PinionLMS.com](https://pinionlms.com/).

We're using "Lato," a Google font.

The problem is that when you load the site from a Win (8.1) browser, FF, Chrome, IE, the font doesn't load and defaults to sans-serif.

Yet, when you load it on a Mac browser it shows up just fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think we need more information to go on with this.

Comment: i'm calling Google fonts in the <head> and assigning style in the CSS file. In local testing everything is fine, the fonts show up, on Win and Mac. It's only out there, live, that Windows browsers don't show the font at all.

Comment: edit your question with the CSS for us to have more to go on, there is no way to know whats happening without knowing what fonts are loaded - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page in developer tool says

> The page at 'https://pinionlms.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Ritesh

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load a font using the `http:` protocol from a page loaded using the `https:` protocol.

Different browsers will react a little different to mixing secure content with unsecure content, and user setting may also affect the way that it is handled. Generally unsecure content will not load in a secure page unless you specifically allow it.

Just change the protocol in the link tag:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

With little information to go on you might want to refer to this

[CSS @font-face not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8)

its possible you are missing the type of IE to be supported.

Comment: Thank you for your time, AlanMorton2.0.